# Working of dsp talking threshold in asterisk 11

Tags: asterisk

I am using talk detection events in asterisk 11. To get the talking events I have set some values for dsp_talking_threshold for e.g. 5000 (ms) which is 5 seconds. I am assuming that I will get the talk events for a channel after the user speaks for 5 seconds continuously, but this is not the case I get the talking event on as soon as the channel start to speak. This will not work because I cannot consider someone talking even if the user says 'yes' or 'no' or any kind of background noise, I will consider someone speaking if I get the voice continuously for 5 seconds.
For more reference I have also set the values for

dsp_drop_silence=yes

talk_detection_events=yes

dsp_talking_threshold=5000

dsp_silence_threshold=5000

Please help me in this and see if I have to do something else.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use application AMD with word length set to 5000.

Create your own event using UserEvent.

Comment: But will this work with confbridge app? I want to detect the talking events in confbridge. I want if channel speaks for atleast 5 seconds then only I get the talk status=on. I tried with AMD and userEvent but it seems it will not work with confbridge. Please let me know if need to do anything else.

Comment: talking events in cofnrbdridge triggered on talk start. If you want change that, you have write your own confbridge.

Comment: in theory - yes, i can. also there are alot of other developer who can. But considering confbridge complexity it will be not simple patch and it will cost also alot.